# System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException, C++/CLI

Tags: c++, visual-studio, c++-cli

I'm sure the code was correct. I'm in C++/CLI environment doing a calling method from database.h
During execution, the line which does the **SQL select statement** encountered System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException,External component has thrown an exception.

**This is C++ enviroment**
database.h

```
int SQLconn::displayData(string model) {
    int count;
    if (con == NULL) {
        cout << "Please setup connection first!";
        system("Pause");
    }else {
        stmt = con->createStatement();
        res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT Model, COUNT(*) FROM database WHERE Model = '" + model + "'");

        while (res->next()) {
        count = res->getInt("COUNT(*)");
        int total = Convert::ToInt32(count);
        return total;
        }
    }
};
```

**This is C++/CLI environment**

```
SQLConn sqlConn;
int sam = sqlConn.displayData("Broom");
                String^ SamCount = sam.ToString();
                this->chart2->Series["occurenceCount"]->Points->AddXY("Broom", SamCount);
```

Comment: Change the debugger type to Mixed and disable "just my code".  Change the exception settings to force the debugger to stop when the Win32 exception is thrown.

Comment: Hello. I managed to check everything on the exception setting but I'm still getting the error

Comment: Are there any possible way to fix this?

Comment: Your code is missing return values on two paths out of three.  Also, the loop is pointless, replace `while` with `if` since it can never repeat.  Furthermore, `Convert::ToInt32` is doing nothing here (there's almost always a better conversion or parsing function to use, but here it actually is totally useless)